# remove multiple items from array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

```
         $data_rows = array();
         $row = array(
                        0 => get_the_title(), //Post Title
                        1 => get_the_content(), //Post Content
                        2 => $image[0], //Post Featured Image
                        3 => get_the_date(), //Post Date
                        4 => get_the_author(), //Post Author
                        5 => $post_categories, //Post Category
                        6 => $post_tag, //Post Tags
                        7 => get_post_status(), //Post Status
                    );
          $data_rows[] = $row;
```

---

right now this array fetching three columns in the format like......

```
Title1 - Content1 - Image1 - Date1 - Author Name1 - Category1 - Tag1 - Status1
```

Now, i want to delete a single row data item "`Title1`", "`Title2`", "`Title3`" by using `key[0]`, how to do that?

I used "`unset()`" also but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the first element try this,

```
array_shift($array);
```

or

```
 $array = array_slice($array, 1);
```

or `array_splice()` refer to [Jason Swan's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43965371/6521116)

If you want to remove multi first element, use array_map() and above mothods.

```
$result = array_map(function($v){return array_slice($v, 1);}, $multidimensionarray);
```

Comment: "$multidimensionarray" indicating..?

Comment: your $data_rows

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `array_splice()`?

Syntax: `array_splice(array,start, (optional) length)`

EDIT: A simple dirty way would be to iterate over the `$data_rows` array and check if the key matches the title. It might not be the most efficient way though.

```
for($i=count($data_rows) - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  if(strpos(key[0], $data_rows[i][0]) !== false){
    array_splice($data_rows[i], 0, 1);
  }
}
```

The reason for iterating backwards is when you splice something, and then move forward one element, you skip the element that would have been next.

Comment: yes , used that also. array_splice also removing only a single row "Title" . It is not removing "Title1" and "Title2"

Comment: @Mukiikumar What are you trying to remove? The title from each of the rows? Or the row based upon the title itself?

Comment: All the titles from each rows.

Comment: @Mukiikumar based upon the key[0]? So if key[0] is "Title1" you want to remove the Title element from the row with the title "Title1"? Or just remove every title that contains the key[0]?

Comment: Yes, every title that containing the key[0].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144198/discussion-between-jason-swan-and-mukii-kumar).